# How do I switch partials with Node JS and Sails JS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a 'My Scores' view in my Node JS / Sails JS app and I'm using partials, one for a List View, and another one for a Grid View. When the user clicks the Grid or List View from the nav bar I'd like to be able to swap the UI with the given partial.

List view:

```
<div class="content-container">

    <h1>My Scores</h1>

    <%- partial('../partials/list-view')%>

</div>
```

Grid view:

```
<div class="content-container">

    <h1>My Scores</h1>

    <%- partial('../partials/grid-view')%>

</div>
```

Please advise.

Comment: One thought is that I could just load both partials, hide unused one via CSS, and swap them when the user switches between List and Grid view. But that feels like perhaps I isn't a best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem--just use a variable for the partial name, instead of hardcoding it:

```
<%- partial(viewName) %>
```

then in your **config/routes.js**:

```
"/listView": {
    view: "list.ejs",
    locals: {viewName: "../partials/list-view.ejs"}
},
"/gridView": {
    view: "list.ejs",
    locals: {viewName: "../partials/grid-view.ejs"}
}
```

That's assuming you're just routing directly to views.  If you're using a custom controller action and `res.view()` to display your content, you'll put the `viewName` value in the second `res.view()` argument, like `res.view("list.ejs",{viewName: "../partials/list-view.ejs"})`.

Now, if you're trying to do this without reloading the page, then @tonejac has the right idea in his comment--either switch them using Javascript/CSS, or use AJAX to load content on-demand.  Sails can only help on the backend!